# What does this Pokemon Trainer mean by saying the player is "SHELLOS"?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

While challenging the Battle Factory in [Johto's Battle Frontier](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Frontier_(Generation_IV)), a Pokemon Trainer battles with you, and tells you (after defeating him):

> You're just SHELLOS, if I say so myself.

I am Gen I & II Pkmn Trainer, so I don't really know what the characters of the new Pokemon are (for example, I would know that a Blissey would care for others). What does that Trainer mean? In other words, what does SHELLOS mean
in this context?

[image]

After being defeated:

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's a pun. "Shellos", the name of [a Pokémon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shellos_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), sounds like "jealous". The trainer is saying you're just pretending you're not interested in his lifestyle, while actually being jealous of him.

In this case, "envious" would be the correct word to use, but "jealous" is commonly misused as a synonym of "envious".

Comment: I heard the pronunciation of the word Shellos on Google Translate, and it seems that you are right. Maybe if I was a native speaker (or a proficient enough one) I could have thought of that, but nope, so thanks!

Comment: @gsamaras: I'll be honest, I wouldn't have understood it at first either, and I'm a native speaker. I can only imagine how much harder it'd be to figure out as a non-native speaker...

Comment: Keep in mind that this game is translated from Japanese and puns are usually hard to translate. I'd imagine most get dropped and some of them just end up like this.

Comment: @V2Blast Same, I would have needed it to be spelled "Shealous" to be able to potentially get the joke, and even then, I'm not convinced I would have figured it out.

Comment: @Discretelizard Diamond and Pearl did a great job with the localization, and given that this is the Battle Frontier I'm 94% sure that this quote was copied from those games.

Comment: *"jealous" is commonly misused as a synonym of "envious"* TIL. I have gone my entire life thinking they were exact synonyms.

Comment: @Michael (I assume you've probably looked this up by now) but for others; jealousy is (originally) the fear of somebody taking away what you have (e.g. seducing your partner), envy is resentment from somebody having something you don't (e.g. your neighbor now being with your ex-partner...after they seduced them).

Comment: @Michael Depending on how long you've been alive, you may not have been wrong. Languages evolve and words gain meanings - or change meaning entirely - over time, generally dependent on how they've been used (or *mis*used).